# Dealing with pandas SettingWithCopyWarning without indexer

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting the famous SettingWithCopyWarning when writing:

```
df['test'] = pd.factorize(df.test)[0]
```

I have tried

```
df.loc[:, 'test'] = pd.factorize(df.test)[0]
df.loc[:, ('test')] = pd.factorize(df.test)[0]
df[('test')] = pd.factorize(df.test)[0]
df.loc[df.index.tolist(), 'test'] = pd.factorize(df.test)[0]
```

but now sucess, the warning stays. I am not sure what I am doing wrong or how to deal with that. The point - and the difference to other questions at SO - that I do **not** want to use an indexer.

I also consulted http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy without success.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas Might help.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `factorize`?

Comment: @AndrewL: This is just an example. The question is about the warning, not factorize. (I would have to explain the algorithm to explain, why I need this.)

Comment: So.. ignoring the above example you're essentially trying to set an entire column to a single value? This should not throw the error.

Comment: @AndrewL: No, I don't. factorize is not doing that. Please check out https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html - it is returning a tuple.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: There is no solution there I haven't tried.

Comment: Again, a small amount of context around what you're trying to set the column to might help us help you. You are setting `test` to an array?

Comment: @AndrewL: There is a column called `cycleNr` which has lots of integers  which correspond to signal segments that I compare with each other. The result of each comparison. will be placed into a numpy array, where rows correspond to segment1 and columns to segment2 In order to find the right cell to place my results in, I need the segments to have numbers that are from 0 to N, where N is the number of segments. `cycleNr` is a uuid for the segment, but is not in 0..N. The factorization is producing a new uuid if you will. Clear now?

Comment: df is a slice of another dataframe. Set `df.is_copy = None`. See Jeff's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20644369/2285236

Answer (score 0):

If your only issue is to remove the warning, maybe try :

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

That doesn't change anything beside not showing the warning